# cte table does not exist mysql

Tags: mysql, recursion, common-table-expression

I am trying to calculate the number of users who have an active subscription on a particular day. I also want information related to the subscription plan they are on. I have a subscriptions table which includes the start date and end date of subscription as well as the plan name. I am using a recursive cte to find out the number of subscribers of different plans on a date range but I am getting the error that the cte table doesn't exist. I am using the following code.

```
SET @start = (SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM subscriptions);
SET @end = (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM subscriptions);
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT @start dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date_add(dt, interval 1 day) FROM cte
    WHERE dt < @end
)

SELECT cte.dt, SUM(CASE WHEN subscriptions.plan_name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) FROM cte
LEFT JOIN subscriptions t 
ON cte.dt BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date
GROUP BY cte.dt;
```

[the output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMHXk.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the exact error message.

Answer (score 4):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT @start dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date_add(dt, interval 1 day) FROM cte
    WHERE dt < @end
)
```

You are refering `cte` in itself, which makes it *recursive* and needs to be defined as such ([`WITH RECURSIVE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive)).

This is what you need:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT @start dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date_add(dt, interval 1 day) FROM cte
    WHERE dt < @end
)
```

Comment: FWIW, in some other implementations (Microsoft), you can write a recursive CTE query without using the `RECURSIVE` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Check for your mySQL version. CTE is supported from version 8 onwards